# How to get rowIndex in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I have a table using normal HTML in reactjs:

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api/users")
      .then((response) => {
        setUser(response.data);
      });
  }, [url]);

const [rowIndex, setRowIndex] = useState("");

if (user) {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Age</th>
              <th scope="col">Department</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {user.map((item) => (
              <tr>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.age}</td>
                <td>{item.department}</td>
                <td><button>Click</button></td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

If in **Javascript**, I can simply set `<tr onclick="getIndex(this)">` and calling `function getIndex(x) {console.log(x.rowIndex)}` to get the row number.

But it's not working in **ReactJS**. How can I get the **rowIndex** in **ReactJS**?

Comment: use `{user.map((item, index) => (`

Comment: `<tr onClick={e => getIndex(e.target)}>` since arrow functions have no `this` but i would go for @Apostolos comment solution

Comment: From the map method 2nd parameter, you can get the current Iteration index.
eg: user.map((item, index) => { console.log(index)})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use index inside your `map` method and then use this variable inside your button's `onClick` method

```
 const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

 useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://localhost:8080/api/users")
      .then((response) => {
        setUser(response.data);
      });
  }, [url]);

const [rowIndex, setRowIndex] = useState("");

if (user) {
    return (
      <div>
        <table className="table">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Name</th>
              <th scope="col">Age</th>
              <th scope="col">Department</th>
              <th scope="col">Action</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            {user.map((item, index) => (
              <tr>
                <td>{item.name}</td>
                <td>{item.age}</td>
                <td>{item.department}</td>
                <td><button onclick={() => setRowIndex(index)}>Click</button></td>
              </tr>
            ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    );
  }
```